# Adding Parameters to connect and scrape data from a Dynamic URL

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

If i try to add parameters by splicing the string of the URL with my variables it does not connect to the URL.  To simplify the problem in my code i am hard coding the variable values but normally I would be pulling this from a named range.

I have tried power queries Advanced "Get Data from Web" feature but cant seem to add the parameters

```
Sub OpenWebStockDataTest()
'
' OpenWebStockDataTest Macro
'

'
    Dim sticker As String
    Dim exchange As String

    sticker = "TGIF"
    exchange = "CN"

    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 2", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & sticker & "." & exchange & "/history?p=" & sticker & "." & exchange & """))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data2 = Source{2}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data2,{{""Date"", type date}, {""Open"", type number}, {""High"", type number}, {""Low"", type number}, {""Close*"", type number}, {""Adj Close**"", type number}, {""Volume"", Int64" & _
        ".Type}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table 2"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table 2]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_2"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

The above code should connect to: 
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TGIF.CN/history?p=TGIF.CN

Please someone Help!!!

Comment: I think you need to `Debug.Print` that long string that the `Formula` is supposed to be. Then compare the output carefully to what you expect it to be.

Comment: i used the MsgBox to display the string of the URL and it displays correctly.... that part of the code was created by the macro recorder so i am not sure what the other arguments are part of the Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents() part....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting lost in your quotes.

```
"    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"" & sticker & ""."" & exchange &""/history?p="" &sticker &"".""&exchange)),"
```

should be

```
"    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & sticker & "." & exchange & "/history?p=" & sticker & "." & exchange & """)),"
```

**Edit:**

```
Sub OpenWebStockDataTest()
'
' OpenWebStockDataTest Macro
'

'
    Dim sticker As String
    Dim exchange As String

    sticker = "TGIF"
    exchange = "CN"

    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 2", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & sticker & "." & exchange & "/history?p=" & sticker & "." & exchange & """))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data2 = Source{2}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data2,{{""Date"", type date}, {""Open"", type number}, {""High"", type number}, {""Low"", type number}, {""Close*"", type number}, {""Adj Close**"", type number}, {""Volume"", Int64" & _
        ".Type}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table 2"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table 2]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_2"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I gave that a try but it gives me the exact same result.  For some reason it doesnt seem to connect and scrape the data from:  https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TGIF.CN/history?p=TGIF.CN  into a query named "Table_2"

Comment: Can you update your original post with the corrected string?

Comment: Not quite. I'll post the fully corrected code. It works fine for me.

Comment: HI Nathan, its working for me now.  Sorry for that confusion and thanks so much for your help!!!  I am past that bug and on to the next one....